# Is it possible to wrap a templated class with pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, templates, pybind11

Just a simple class as an example:

```
template <int n>
Class MyClass
{
public:
    void show_n(); // prints n out
}
```

Now I want to wrap this to expose as a Python class:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(MyModule, handle) {
    py::class_<MyClass<5>>(handle)
    .def("show_n", &MyClass<5>::show_n);
}
```

Now I want the template parameter to be defined in Python. How can I pass it from Python? Is it possible?

Comment: Templates are a compile-time mechanism, they are not present in the resulting binary. Since you only use compiled C++ code in Python, the answer is simply "no".

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt just as I suspected. Could you put that as an answer?